# clang-format: Break before braces for lambda functions and extern blocks

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, clang-format

I have a lambda function formatted like this:

```cpp
auto cb = [](std::string const& _param)
{
    std::cout << _param;
};
```

I would like to keep the opening brace on a new line, but `clang-format` always places it at the end of the first line. Is it possible to configure `clang-format` to follow the style above?

The relevant part of my current configuration looks like this:

```
BraceWrapping:                         
  AfterClass:      true   
  AfterControlStatement: true
  AfterEnum:       true
  AfterFunction:   true          
  AfterNamespace:  true                
  AfterStruct:     true
  AfterUnion:      true
  BeforeCatch:     true
  BeforeElse:      true   
  IndentBraces:    true
BreakBeforeBraces: Allman
```

I would also like to do the same for `extern` blocks:

```
extern "C"
{
  // ...
}
```

Comment: What version of `clang-format` are you using? This might be a bug: https://www.mail-archive.com/llvm-bugs@lists.llvm.org/msg05471.html

Comment: I am using version 5.0.0 (tags/google/stable/2017-03-17)

Comment: I just found bug reports tracking the problem with lambdas https://bugs.llvm.org//show_bug.cgi?id=32151 and extern blocks https://bugs.llvm.org//show_bug.cgi?id=26689

Comment: I believe all of your BraceWrapping values are ignored if you don't have BreakBeforeBraces set to Custom.

Comment: I believe more related is https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=27640

Answer (score 9):

This appears to be addressed with `BeforeLambdaBody` introduced in clang-format 11.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think there is an option for this particular case. I am sorry if you don't consider this as an answer, but when I have these "fine tuning" problems with clang-format, I just format the snippet as I want and comment `clang-format off` just before the interesting snippet and `clang-format on`  right after. I often do that to maintain some blank character sequence used to align code for better reading. The effect is of course that CF will not change that snippet. So your code may be

```
// clang-format off
auto cb = [](std::string const& _param)
{
    std::cout << _param;
};
// clang-format on
```